# happy thoughts, encouragement requested

Tags: phd, advisor

My phd advisor is being abusive. I cannot switch - too close to the end. Dissertation is mediocre and I cannot get the help I need to improve. Adviser's colleagues will publish the main ideas of diss without me (long story) because of data overlap. Please send a happy thought or encouragement. I would like something non-school-related to distract me, Sorry so plaintive.

Comment: Let me note that you aren't alone. There are many questions here (actual questions) asking for advice about how to deal with such a situation and how to get out of it. I suggest you explore. Start by looking for questions with the [tag:advisor] tag.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I don't know what kind of answer I can give since this is not really an academic related query.

Three things come to mind - and this is coming from someone who spends quite a bit of their time soul-searching and sometimes depressed.

1. Get out the house. Spend time away from the internet, the answers do not lie there. Turn your smartphone off. Go to the park, go to a museum, go to a bar, go to the cinema, go to a gig. Yes, you can do all of these things on your own. It's not 'sad', it's fun and kind of arty/Parisian. Just spend time enjoying what life has to offer away from your PhD. If you can, spend a couple of nights away in a different city. It can be close, it can be abroad, depending on what's available to you. Go out with friends, discuss your issues over a few drinks. Spend time with people who care about you and will listen to you.
2. Escapism through art is a good idea. Watch some films, listen to some music. When I am really down, I find that listening to certain artists remind me what's beautiful about life away from the other troubles that often present themselves [I recommend *The Moon and the Nightspirit*'s albums "Regő Rejtem" or "Holdrejtek"].
3. Even though this is something of an academic reply, I have been going through similar personal issues recently and I would recommend Ehsan's advice [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/132559/68021) - he earned his 400 rep points there.

Good luck and try to stay positive.